# "schematic -->" in answers with multiple CircuitLab schematics

Tags: bug

First time I noticed this bug, I though I may had made a typo, but now I spot the same bug again.

[image]

As someone may edit out the bug, this is what it looks like in the editor pane. Notice the stray "schematic -->" about half way:

```
<!-- Begin schematic: In order to preserve an editable schematic, please
     don't edit this section directly.
     Click the "edit" link below the image in the preview instead. -->

![schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsZPW.png)

<!-- End schematic -->

 schematic -->

Y&rarr;Δ
-

\$
R_{ab} = R_{an} + R_{bn} + \frac{ R_{an} × R_{bn} }{ R_{cn} }
\$
```

[Basic rules to calculate the equivalent resistance of a resistor circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/60977/basic-rules-to-calculate-the-equivalent-resistance-of-a-resistor-circuit/60979?noredirect=1#comment117077_60979)

I think it happens when you edit a circuit diagram in an article with multiple circuits.

At the same time part of the answer text vanishes, but I edited that back in again (2nd time too):

> allel resistors: \$R_P = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{R_3}+\frac{1}{R_4}}\$